# What is the difference between Gridseed ASIC and Scrypt ASIC

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, asic, miner-configuration

If you mine in wemineltc pool you have probably noticed that there are two different stratum server for ASIC miners 
here are the urls 
[image]

So my question is that *what is the difference between an gridseed asic and scrypt acis miner ???*

And I will be thankful if you explain me that what is gridseed mean exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gridseeds are small dual-mode miners offering SHA256 and Scrypt.

[image: gridseeds]

Gridseeds have a very low scrypt hashrate (<400kH/s). The hashrate affects the share difficulty and therefore it's quite a good idea to offer a seperate mining port for low hashrate devices.

It seems there are so many gridseeds still out there that it's worth to mention that on the pools help page.